# Different result between Query and stored procedure

Tags: mysql

So here is my query

```
SELECT count(distinct (id_customer)) as customer
from `orders`
WHERE order_date >= '2022-06-01 08:30%' AND order_date <= '2022-06-06 08:30%';
```

the result is **2069**.

Then I create this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_count(IN start_date DATE, IN end_date DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT count(distinct (id_customer)) as customer
    from `orders`
    WHERE order_date >= start_date AND order_date <= end_date;
END;
```

and then call it using

```
CALL customer_count('2022-06-01 08:30%', '2022-06-06 08:30%');
```

it return **2126**

I have done some googling but still no luck.

Comment: Hard to say without any tablestructure or exampledata ... What happens if you do `CALL customer_count('2022-06-01 08:30%', '2022-06-06 08:30%');` So that you have the same parameters in the Stored Procedure as in the query? Or vice versa: Remove the `%` (what are they even there for) from the query?

Comment: What data types are start_date ande end_date in your database?

Comment: @RossBush its datetime

Comment: @derpirscher I tried it and it return the same number 2126, because in database there may be data with different seconds but still want to include as long as it begin with 08:30 , therefore i use 08:30% , or is there better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had used the DATE datatype in procedure parameters so then it compares only date value.

please change the DATE datatype to DATETIME, You will get expected output and don't use % (wild character search) in date columns.

Better use following query:

```
SELECT count(distinct (id_customer)) as customer
from `orders`
WHERE order_date >= '2022-06-01 08:30:00' AND order_date <= '2022-06-06 08:30:59';
```

Change the procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_count(IN start_date DATETIME, IN end_date DATETIME)
BEGIN
SELECT count(distinct (id_customer)) as customer
from `orders`
WHERE order_date >= start_date AND order_date <= end_date;
END;
```

Comment: I'd personally would ditch the `<= '2022-06-06 08:30:59'` in favour of a `< '2022-06-06 08:31'`. This way, you can be sure you also include a timestamp like 08:30:59.999